# Progressive JPEG

Tags: images, browsers, browser-support, jpeg

This Post: ["Progressive" JPEG: Why do many web sites avoid rendering JPEGs that way? Pros, cons?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/574/progressive-jpeg-why-do-many-web-sites-avoid-rendering-jpegs-that-way-pros-c) stat that many browsers do not support Progressive JPEG citing this [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).

What I have not found is which browsers do and do not support it.

I know FF 7 supports it but I have not tested the other browsers to know.

Does anyone have a comparison chart or something similar?

Bonus Question: What e-mail clients support Progressive JPEG? (Desktop E-Mail Clients e.g. Outlook & Thunerbird etc)

---

So I decided to run few test to see how browsers handled Progressive JPEGs. Here is what I found:

- Firefox 7 - Displayed Correctly
- Internet Explorer 7 & 8 - Displayed
  Photo once finished downloaded (Did not load scan by scan)
- Safari 5 -
  Displayed Photo once finished downloaded (Did not load scan by scan)
- Chrome 13 - Display Correctly
- Opera 11.5 - Displayed Correctly

If anyone has any comments to my test or any thoughts please let me know (Including how older browsers of the ones that did load it correctly work).

I am still wondering about email clients if anyone can help with that.

Comment: I think all supports progressive, I'm using them since IE6 and they have been always rendered. In the worst case browsers/email-clients won't render the progressive effect, but they will still finally render the image, so it does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Marco's comment is the correct answer in this instance, whilst most do ones that don't will display the image anyway.

Something you might find useful is this Wikipedia article on [Browser Image Format support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support).

Comment: Very nice information in that article. There is also a nice site that has information about browsers and what they can use: caniuse.com/